# Grails data binding with a query

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm

Assuming a domain class with a simple association:

```
class User {    
    Country country
}
```

Grails by default allows binding it by id:

```
new User(country: 1).country
≫ Country: 1
```

I'm trying to use the BindUsing annotation to bind it by another property:

```
class User {    
    @BindUsing({ obj, src -> 
        Country.findByCode(src['country']) 
    })
    Country country
}
```

But it fails, even though the country exists:

```
Country.findByCode('US') 
≫ Country: 1

new User(country: 'US').country
≫ null
```

Moreover, I can't seem to be able to debug the closure, because if I try to print anything coming from the `src` object, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method
    java.io.PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Printing constant values works.

Comment: which grails version are you using?

Comment: I tried it on 2.3.8, and its working fine without any issues even after adding the println statement to closure.

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.5.0

Comment: It works fine in 2.5.0. also. Try clean-all and then recompile